# Angular $http.post not working, works using postman

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, ionic-framework

I've created an Ionic app which calls an API to post the user's current location.

The request works as follows:
POST: http://mywebsite.com/api/Patients/AddLocation/17
with body:

```
{
"Latitude": 51.3753786,
"Longitude": -0.0833691
}
```

However, the following code in my Ionic app does work:

```
$http.post('http://mywebsite.com/api/Patients/AddLocation/' + $scope.id, data)
                    .success(function () {
                        console.log('Updated location');
                    })
                    .error(function (error) {
                        console.log('Error updating location');
                        console.log("Error: " + error);
                    });
```

In which 'data' is the same as the body above.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

UPDATE:
Here's a couple of screenshots of the network request:
Network request available at imgur RWNDF.png
[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATY2a.png)

Comment: maybe CORS. check the browser console for any errors

Comment: I don't think it is - the console doesn't mention anything about that and there are several other http requests (including POST which have the same format) which work fine. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: What is the data that you are expecting at server side ?

Comment: Are you sure `.error(function(error) {` is reached in your code? The `$http`'s `success(...).error(...)` callbacks have been removed in the Angular 1.6, not sure which version ionic uses, though

Comment: @GangadharJannu - It's expecting an ID in the request address, and a JSON object with 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' attributes. This works when using postman (even when using the address and body generated from the code - obtained using chrome://inspect)

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of the request in network tab ?

Comment: @crizzis - Yep - it run the console.log statements.

Comment: @GangadharJannu - see screenshot about. Thanks

Comment: Could you also show the network response?

Comment: Did you disable the web security in google chrome?

Comment: @ShellyCoburn - It doesn't seem like there is actually a response. On the reponse tab it just says "Failed to load response data"

Comment: @GangadharJannu - No, how does one do this?

Comment: Open your run prompt and type 'chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:\chrome".It should display a notification that 'web-security has been disabled'. Then try to hit the service.

Comment: @GangadharJannu - Gave that a go but still hitting the same issue

Comment: Would you mind to add the screenshot of service in postman also?

Comment: @GangadharJannu See update, thanks!

Comment: There is an option in postman which allows us to generate the request in specific programming language. Try to get the request format in javascript and check whether the request format is matching with yours $http request

Comment: This seems to be the same - interesting update however. It now seems all POST requests are acting in the same way from within this app.

Comment: "Failed to load response data" sounds like response misconfiguration issue (e.g. the response status being 200 instead of 204 even though the content is empty, or declaring an invalid response `Content-Type`)

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you have not  enabled cors in your server.
enable cors in you server.
even if you dont enable cors,
get method will work peerfectly if you have enabled cors using any extension in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of CORS. Enable cros from the server end and the a header will be set in HTTP `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` .

If your server app is an `expressjs app`, use below code to enable CORS

```
var cors = require('cors'); 
..... 
app.use(cors());
```

Else use chrome extension [Allow Cross Origin Request](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi%3Fhl%3Den&ved=0ahUKEwjR-efokd7SAhXBsY8KHY_XDSIQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNHSUFqc6ylxfxfbWzmmFJ6L5QUvyg)

This should solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already installed the chrome extension, I make other POST requests within the same app which are successful (such as registering a user) so I don't think it's a CORS issue. Hm....

Answer (score 0):

After comparing this to a sister app which uses the same API and works, the only difference I could see was that a few of the plugins were different.

To remedy this I deleted the plugins folder and the platforms folder, re-added android and just the plugins I need, it now works. I guess it's maybe some bug I created by using the wrong mixture of plugins.

A very unsatisfying answer, but all requests work now!